# Sanitize optional undefined values as null

Tags: javascript, validation, express-validator

I'm trying to sanitize `undefined` optional values to be `null`.

I tried this:

```
body('value').isNumeric().optional().default(null)
```

But it only works when `value` is not allowed to be `.optional()`.

I also tried `.customSanitizer(value => value || null)` but it fails for the same reason.

Comment: Doesn't `.default()` imply that it's optional?

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try `.replace([undefined], null)`: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/sanitization-chain-api.html#replacevalues_to_replace-new_value